# Quick question on multivariate differentiation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Does $$\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x \partial y}$$ mean diff it wrt $x$ THEN wrt $y$? Or diff wrt $y$ then wrt $x$?

Comment: They should be partial differentials, no?

Comment: Yes sorry it should be partial

Comment: If the order matters then I don't think it makes sense to write a derivative in this form. Either way should come up with the same answer.

Comment: We were told that sometimes the order does matter if rare cases like when the function is not smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual interpretation is
$$
\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x \partial y}
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f
,
$$
so $y$ first, then $x$.

(Just to give a reference to a standard textbook, this is how it's defined in *Calculus: A Complete Course* by Adams.)

Answer (score 1):

It means to differentiate with respect to $y$ first and then differentiate with respect to $x$. This is consistent with the operator notation, in which differentiating with respect to $y$ and then with respect to $x$ would look like:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f \right ).$$

So you get the shorter notation by "multiplying out" the operator notation in the "numerator" and "denominator", just as in one variable calculus.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter what order you do it in, as partial differentiation is a commutative operation, i.e.:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)
$$

Edit: as Ian stated, this assumes sufficient smoothness (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives), for example). In the case where it did matter, I would expect (hope) that the order or the notation would be somehow stated explicitly and you would not be left to infer it on your own.

Comment: In the absence of sufficient smoothness, this is not true, at least not in the classical sense. The usual sufficient condition is that the second partials are all continuous.